# Cant connect to WCF Service. Missing EndPointElemt

Tags: c#, wcf, channelfactory

i'm trying to create my own WCF service and client. I've created my Service with the following app.config settings:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="Interface.MyWCFService">
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:9999/MyService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="" name="MyServiceEndpoint" contract="Interface.IMyWCFService" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The service starts without an exception.

My client should connect to this service. His app.config is this one:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
             <endpoint address="http://localhost:9999/MyService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="" contract="Interface.IMyWCFService"
                  name="MyServiceEndpoint" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In the c# code i try to create a channelfactory in the client.cs with the following code:

```
 ChannelFactory<IMyWCFService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyWCFService>("MyServiceEndpoint", new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:9999/MyService"));

        IMyWCFService proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

This is not working. Every time i try to start the program i get the following exception:

> No Endpointelement with the name "MyServiceEndpoint" and contract
>   "Interface.IMyWCFService" was found in
>   ServiceModel-Clientconfigurationsection.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have my service configured:

```
  <service name="foo.bar.BlaService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/BlaService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="foo.bar.IBlaService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

And here the client:

```
<client>
  <endpoint name="BlaService" address="http://localhost/BlaService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="foo.bar.IBlaService" />
</client>
```

Comment: The error refers to the endpoint, not the service.  OP's service config looks correct, and the error is in the client anyway, not the service.

Comment: Ok, since the error is localized to the client, any idea?

Comment: @Christoph, have you tried my suggestion? In WCF certain settings have to be in sync between the server and the client...

Comment: Hey, with your settings the service is not starting any more. There is another exception when opening the servicehost. The service has no application endpoint

Comment: @Christoph, just described how I normally do. Does this help? I can create a channel with these settings...